# XCom pull by task_ids doesn't get value

Tags: python, airflow

I have a simple dag which has two tasks in task group.
This dag has schedule every 10 minutes to pull message from google pub/sub. However the pull sensor working well to get messages, but on the next task doesn't get the message which already pushed to XCom.

Here is my dag

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import Variable
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.sensors.pubsub import PubSubPullSensor
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.task_group import TaskGroup
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from dags.python_scripts.airflow_callback import callback
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import base64
import json

# Airflow Config
default_args = {
    'owner': 'data',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': days_ago(1),
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'email': [],
    'retries': 5,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(seconds=300),
    'on_failure_callback': callback
}

def extract_datetime(**kwargs):
    message_data = kwargs['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids='pull_pubsub_message')
    print("MESSAGE FROM PUB/SUB", message_data)

    decoded_data = [base64.b64decode(message['message']['data']) for message in message_data]
    print("pubsub data received: ", decoded_data)
    for d in decoded_data:
        decoded_d = json.loads(str(d.decode("utf-8")))
        payload_datetime = datetime.strptime(decoded_d['run_datetime'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        # Extract the date portion from the datetime
        extracted_date = payload_datetime.date()

        # Pass the extracted date as a parameter to the BigQuery operator
        kwargs['ti'].xcom_push(key='extracted_date', value=extracted_date)


dag_id = "ingest_score"
with DAG(
        dag_id,
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule_interval='*/10 * * * *',
        catchup=False,
        concurrency=1,
        max_active_runs=1,
        dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=10)
) as dag:

    task_finish_ingestion = EmptyOperator(
        task_id='ingestion_finished',
        dag=dag,
    )

    with TaskGroup('recommender_feed'):

        pull_pubsub_message_task = PubSubPullSensor(
            task_id='pull_pubsub_message',
            ack_messages=True,
            max_messages=100,
            timeout=100,
            project_id="{{ var.value.PUBSUB_PROJECT_ID }}",
            subscription="{{ var.value.PUBSUB_SUBSCRIBER }}",
            soft_fail=True
        )

        extract_datetime_task = PythonOperator(
            task_id='extract_datetime',
            python_callable=extract_datetime
        )


    # Set up task dependencies
    pull_pubsub_message_task >> extract_datetime_task >> task_finish_ingestion
```

Here is the log of `pull_sub_message_task`

```
</br>
2023-10-05T01:10:05.988+0000 logLevel=INFO logger=airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.pubsub.PubSubHook - Pulling max 100 messages from subscription (path) projects/my-project-id/subscriptions/scoring-sub 
</br>
2023-10-05T01:10:08.883+0000 logLevel=INFO logger=airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.pubsub.PubSubHook - Pulled 1 messages from subscription (path) projects/my-project-id/subscriptions/scoring-sub 
</br>
2023-10-05T01:10:08.884+0000 logLevel=INFO logger=airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.pubsub.PubSubHook - Acknowledging 1 ack_ids from subscription (path) projects/my-project-id/subscriptions/scoring-sub 
</br>
2023-10-05T01:10:08.967+0000 logLevel=INFO logger=airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.pubsub.PubSubHook - Acknowledged ack_ids from subscription (path) projects/my-project-id/subscriptions/scoring-sub 
</br>
2023-10-05T01:10:08.974+0000 logLevel=INFO logger=airflow.task.operators - Success criteria met. Exiting.
```

Here is the log of `extract_datetime_task`, you can see message_data is `None`

```
2023-10-05T01:10:12.991+0000 logLevel=INFO logger=airflow.task - Executing <Task(PythonOperator): recommender_feed.extract_datetime> on 2023-10-05 01:00:00+00:00 
</br>
2023-10-05T01:10:12.998+0000 logLevel=INFO logger=airflow.task.task_runner.standard_task_runner.StandardTaskRunner - Started process 7658 to run task 
</br>
2023-10-05T01:10:13.002+0000 logLevel=INFO logger=airflow.task.task_runner.standard_task_runner.StandardTaskRunner - Running: ['***', 'tasks', 'run', 'ingest_score', 'recommender_feed.extract_datetime', 'scheduled__2023-10-05T01:00:00+00:00', '--job-id', '114', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/dags/ingest_score.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmp54e9omke'] 
</br>
2023-10-05T01:10:13.005+0000 logLevel=INFO logger=airflow.task.task_runner.standard_task_runner.StandardTaskRunner - Job 114: Subtask recommender_feed.extract_datetime 
</br>
2023-10-05T01:10:13.998+0000 logLevel=INFO logger=airflow.cli.commands.task_command - Running <TaskInstance: ingest_score.recommender_feed.extract_datetime scheduled__2023-10-05T01:00:00+00:00 [running]> on host ***-worker-0.***-worker.***.svc.cluster.local 
</br>
2023-10-05T01:10:15.036+0000 logLevel=INFO logger=airflow.task - Exporting env vars: AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER='data' AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID='ingest_score' AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID='recommender_feed.extract_datetime' AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE='2023-10-05T01:00:00+00:00' AIRFLOW_CTX_TRY_NUMBER='1' AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID='scheduled__2023-10-05T01:00:00+00:00' 
</br>
2023-10-05T01:10:15.049+0000 logLevel=INFO logger=airflow.task - MESSAGE FROM PUB/SUB None 
</br>
```

The value is exists on the XComs UI
[image]

airflow 2.6.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because You put the pub_sub task under taskgroup its id is : {id_of_group}.{task_id} :  recommender_feed.pull_pubsub_message

change this to :

```
message_data = kwargs['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids='recommender_feed.pull_pubsub_message')
```

Comment: ah I missed that.. thx